# Does subject labelling affect p-values of a lmer model in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data, lme4

I encounter a problem while running an R script.
The study is a within-subject study.
I run a linear mixed-effect model:

```
lmer(var1 ~ cond1 * cond2 + (1|subj) + (1 | var2) + (1 | var3), data = data)
```

- var1: the response variable
- cond1: a factor with 2 levels
- cond2: a factor with 2 levels
- subj: ID of the subject, stored as a factor
- var2: a response variable with a random effect
- var3: a response variable with a random effect

The issue that I have is with the variable subj.

I obtain different p-values for `cond1*cond2` depending on the labelling of the variable subj, which is always stored as a factor.

It was first tried with numbers:

```
Factor w/ 22 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Then different numbers:

```
Factor w/ 22 levels "41","42","43",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

And finally characters combined with numbers:

```
Factor w/ 22 levels "L1","L10","L11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

While I would not expect the values attributed to different levels of a factor to have any influence at all on the results of the analysis,
I find that changing the labels of the subjects ID substantially changes my results. Have you ever encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: Just a guess: when dealing with factors we omit one of the levels (automatically the first one, that by default is alphabetically ordered) to avoid perfect multicolinearity. It can be that changing the levels of your factor changes the one chosen to be omitted and that might affect you p-values.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. This might be relevant as in the analysis, we merge two data sets from two different populations together, and we have to differentiate two labelling for 'subj', initially identical in the two original data sets.